# Understanding LDA / topic modelling -- too much topic overlap

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I'm new to topic modelling / Latent Dirichlet Allocation and have trouble understanding how I can apply the concept to my dataset (or whether it's the correct approach).

I have a small number of literary texts (novels) and would like to extract some general topics using LDA.

I'm using the `gensim` module in Python along with some `nltk` features. For a test I've split up my original texts (just 6) into 30 chunks with 1000 words each. Then I converted the chunks into document-term matrices and ran the algorithm. This is the code (although I think it doesn't matter for the question) :

```
# chunks is a 30x1000 words matrix

dictionary = gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary(chunks)
corpus = [ dictionary.doc2bow(chunk) for chunk in chunks ]
lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus = corpus, id2word = dictionary,
    num_topics = 10)
topics = lda.show_topics(5, 5)
```

However the result is completely different from any example I've seen in that the topics are full of meaningless words that can be found in *all* source documents, e.g. "I", "he", "said", "like", ... example:

```
[(2, '0.009*"I" + 0.007*"\'s" + 0.007*"The" + 0.005*"would" + 0.004*"He"'), 
(8, '0.012*"I" + 0.010*"He" + 0.008*"\'s" + 0.006*"n\'t" + 0.005*"The"'), 
(9, '0.022*"I" + 0.014*"\'s" + 0.009*"``" + 0.007*"\'\'" + 0.007*"like"'), 
(7, '0.010*"\'s" + 0.009*"I" + 0.006*"He" + 0.005*"The" + 0.005*"said"'), 
(1, '0.009*"I" + 0.009*"\'s" + 0.007*"n\'t" + 0.007*"The" + 0.006*"He"')]
```

I don't quite understand why that happens, or why it doesn't happen with the examples I've seen. How do I get the LDA model to find more distinctive topics with less overlap? Is it a matter of filtering out more common words first? How can I adjust how many times the model runs? Is the number of original texts too small?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

LDA is extremely dependent on the words used in a corpus and how frequently they show up. The words you are seeing are all stopwords - meaningless words that are the most frequent words in a language e.g. "the", "I", "a", "if", "for", "said" etc. and since these words are the most frequent, it will negatively impact the model.

I would use the `nltk` stopword corpus to filter out these words:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
```

Then make sure your text does not contain any of the words in the `stop_words` list (by whatever pre processing method you are using) - an example is below

```
text = text.split() # split words by space and convert to list
text = [word for word in text if word not in stop_words]
text = ' '.join(text) # join the words in the text to make it a continuous string again
```

You may also want to remove punctuation and other characters ("/","-") etc.) then use regular expressions:

```
import re
remove_punctuation_regex = re.compile(r"[^A-Za-z ]") # regex for all characters that are NOT A-Z, a-z and space " "
text = re.sub(remove_punctuation_regex, "", text) # sub all non alphabetical characters with empty string ""
```

Finally, you may also want to filter on most frequent or least frequent words in your corpus, which you can do using nltk:

```
from nltk import FreqDist
all_words = text.split() # list of all the words in your corpus
fdist = FreqDist(all_words) # a frequency distribution of words (word count over the corpus)
k = 10000 # say you want to see the top 10,000 words
top_k_words, _ = zip(*fdist.most_common(k)) # unzip the words and word count tuples
print(top_k_words) # print the words and inspect them to see which ones you want to keep and which ones you want to disregard
```

That should get rid of the stopwords and extra characters, but still leaves the vast problem of topic modelling (which I wont try to explain here but will leave some tips and links).

Assuming you know a little bit about topic modelling, lets start. LDA is a bag of words model, meaning word order doesnt matter. The model assigns a topic distribution (of a predetermined number of topics K) to each document, and a word distribution to each topic. A very insightful [high level video explains this here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mHy4OSyRf0). If you want to see more of the mathematics, but still at an accessible level, check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyuBTMaKFmU&t=193s). The more documents the better, and usually longer documents (with more words) also fair better using LDA - [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.402.4032&rep=rep1&type=pdf) shows that LDA doesnt perform well with short texts (less than ~20 words). K is up to you to choose, and really depends on your corpus of documents (how large it is, what different topics it covers etc.). Usually a good value of K is between 100-300, but again this really depends on your corpus.

LDA has two hyperparamters, alpha and beta (alpha and eta in gemsim) - a higher alpha means each text will be represented by more topics (so naturally a lower alpha means each text will be represented by less topics). A high eta means each topic is represented by more words, and a low eta means each topic is represented by less words - so with a low eta you would get less "overlap" between topics.

There's many insights you could gain using LDA

1. What are the topics in a corpus (naming topics may not matter to your application, but if it does this can be done by inspecting the words in a topic as you have done above)
2. What words contribute most to a topic
3. What documents in the corpus are most similar (using a [similarity metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence))

Hope this has helped. I was new to LDA a few months ago but I've quickly gotten up to speed using stackoverflow and youtube!

Comment: If you feel this answered your question @OP, don't be afraid to click the green check mark and mark this as the correct answer :) if not, please let me know if there's anywhere where I can expand on / explain better

Comment: Does `beta` in LDA have the exact same effect as `eta` in gemsim?